# Permission denied (publickey) in gitlab self hosted server

Tags: ssh, gitlab, docker-compose

I want to setup a ssh connection to my gitlab server.

### gitlab spec

Install via `docker-compose` :

```
# ---------------------- #
#         gitlab         #
# ---------------------- #
gitlab:
  image: gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest
  restart: always
  hostname: gitlab.host.dev
  ports:
    - '801:80'
    - '4433:443'
    - '2222:22'
  volumes:
    - ./config:/etc/gitlab
    - ./logs:/var/log/gitlab
    - ./data:/var/opt/gitlab
  environment:
    GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG: |
      external_url 'http://gitlab.host.dev'
      gitlab_rails['smtp_enable'] = true
      gitlab_rails['smtp_address'] = "smtp.gmail.com"
      gitlab_rails['smtp_port'] = 587
      gitlab_rails['smtp_user_name'] = "a@gmail.com"
      gitlab_rails['smtp_password'] = "xyz"
      gitlab_rails['smtp_domain'] = "smtp.gmail.com"
      gitlab_rails['smtp_authentication'] = "login"
      gitlab_rails['smtp_enable_starttls_auto'] = true
      gitlab_rails['smtp_tls'] = false
      gitlab_rails['smtp_openssl_verify_mode'] = 'peer'
```

In the image :

`cd /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell/`

```
ls -al

[...]
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    39 Sep  7 18:19 config.yml -> /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-shell/config.yml
[...]
```

`cd /var/opt/gitlab/.ssh/`

```
ls -al

-rw-------  1 git  git  3036 Sep 10 08:30 authorized_keys
-rw-r--r--  1 git  git     0 Sep 10 08:30 authorized_keys.lock
```

### Step

1. I add the key on the SSH Keys setting (for my user in gitlab)

```
ssh-rsa AAAAAAAAAAA= user@hostname
```

2. I create a project `test_ssh` in my gitlab
3. I create a new folder in my computer `mkdir test_ssh` and `touch test.txt`
4. `git init`
5. `git add .`
6. `git commit -am "initial commit`
7. add the gitlab remote `git remote add origin git@gitlab.dn.dev:gitlabuser/test_ssh.git`
8. `git push -u origin master`

### Error

```
git@gitlab.helyx.dev: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Can not read remote depot.

Please check that you have access rights
and that the deposit exists.
```

### Https test

I test the push via https and is work correctly.

1. `git remote add https https://gitlab.dn.dev/user/test_ssh.git`
2. `git push -u https master`

```
To https://gitlab.dn.dev/user/test_ssh.git
   * [new branch]      master -> master
```

Comment: Could I see the output of the following SSH command: `ssh -v -l git gitlab.dn.dev` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have configured your container to expose ssh on port 2222:

```
  ports:
    - '2222:22'
```

But you are not providing the port in your git remote URL. You need to add the port 2222 to your remote URL, something like this:

```
git remote add origin ssh://git@gitlab.dn.dev:2222/test_ssh.git
```

Without this port you are connecting to the SSHd of the server itself, not the one provided by Gitlab.

Other options to provide the port are [listed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1558719/using-a-remote-repository-with-non-standard-port).

Comment: of course what an idiot I do.... So i use ``git remote add origin ssh://git@gitlab.dn.dev:2222/path/to/project.git`` and everything work! Thanks.

Comment: If the primary function of this server is to run gitlab it might be worthwhile to either run the system sshd on a standard port, and gitlabs sshd on the default port, or add a second IP address and bind one service on each interface. That way you don't have to mess around with ports so much.

Comment: the server serves for something else too but I'll see to better organize this!

Answer (score -2):

Check settings in sshd (/etc/ssh/sshd_config)

```
PubkeyAuthentication yes
RSAAuthentication yes
```

and restart sshd

Comment: How does this help with an sshd running in the container?